# Get email address of current logged in user

Tags: cmd.exe, lync

On my machine (windows 7) I want to set a registry key with the current logged in user email address (e.g. firstname.lastname@mydomain.com). Basically I want to install LYNC silently and predefine the log on name. Is there any CMD.exe command to get the email address? Or a RegKey? ADS?

I have Outlook installed and configured. Maybe it is possible to get the mail address from outlook registry?

Comment: This part of a domain?

Comment: @MSX: I updated my question. Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 9):

No need to create a registry entery.

On CMD run `whoami /upn`

Comment: Great answer.  Thanks for a solution without unnecessary dependencies.

Comment: This answer assumes that the UPN is the same as the email. While true for many environments, this is not always the case.

Answer (score 2):

You could use LDAP search with powershell to get the mailbox address.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730967.aspx